# PyGtk: How to unpack boxes

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm looking for a way to unpack boxes again.

So having e.g. a construct like that:

```
# ... 
vbox = gtk.VBox()
hbox = gtk.HBox()
vbox.pack_start(hbox,False, False, 0)

label = gtk.Label("Please insert text:")
entry = gtk.Entry()

hbox.pack_start(label,False, False, 0)
hbox.pack_end(entry,False, False, 0)

vbox.show_all()
# ...
```

I'm wondering how I could remove the hbox out of the vbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each box is also a gtk.Container. Therefore there a method() which is removing the widget from container. 
So

```
vbox.remove(self.hbox)
```

did the trick.

(Only resizing of my dialog is pending ;) )